Is it possible to identify pages dedicated to threads in the Linux kernel?
So I'm working on some process and thread migration code for a project I'm working on with a few others. What I want to do is for process migration we identify the pages for the virtual address space in the kernel and then live migrate them to another machine's address space and pages. That seems straightforward.
Unfortunately threads might be a little more difficult. As of now I want to hook pthread_create() and identify the function pointer and the argument pointer to identify the data in virtual address space for that thread, then identifying the pages dedicated to the thread in the kernel and live migrating the thread pages from the current kernel to the other machine's kernel.
Migrating on-disk counterparts is unnecessary as we are using a unified distributed filesystem acting like one single disk.
Is there a page table specifically for threads in the kernel that I can access per thread to obtain the pages for the thread?
Basing this off Popcorn Linux and NetPopcorn, two very wonderful symphonies of code, which supports process and thread migration but requires compilation with a custom compiler.


...identifying the pages dedicated to the thread...

There are no such dedicated pages in any threading system that I've ever heard of. That's not how "threading" works. You probably will have no trouble identifying a given thread's call stack, and those pages will be used exclusively by the thread; but in general, you should not expect that the heap objects and the static variables that are privately used by a given thread will be located on VM pages that are used only by that thread.
Then of course, there's the problem of shared variables. The whole point of using threads within a process instead of using separate processes is so that the threads can communicate with each other through shared variables. I don't know how you were planning to address those.
If the architecture of your application permits, you may be able to migrate the tasks that your threads perform to other processes and other hosts, but it doesn't make any sense to try to migrate the actual threads.

Is there a page table specifically for threads in the kernel that I can access per thread.

No. The virtual address space belongs to the whole process that contains the threads. There is no per-thread VM space.
